# PHP: including files via routing

Tags: php, routes

I'm having trouble getting my PHP router to functions properly. I'm using Macaw https://github.com/Codingbean/Macaw.

I've set everything up properly my www folders contains index.php, Macaw.php and folder called  application.

I setup my htaccess and followed everything on the Macaw page correctly. As a test, I used the default:

```
Macaw::get('/', function() {
  echo 'Hello world!';
});

Macaw::dispatch();
```

So when I now go to example.com I see `Hello World!`. So now I want to route another page, like about:

```
Macaw::get('/about', function() {   
include 'application/about.php'; 
});

Macaw::dispatch();
```

This then 404s. I've set a 404 callback using Macaw for troubleshooting:

```
Macaw::error(function() {
  echo '404 :: Not Found';
});
```

But that's not showing up, so It's not even routing anything at example.com/about . I can't figure out why this doesn't work though. I've tried including the entire url, no forward slash, etc.. nothing works. Does anyone have any experience using routers with this type of thing? What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are only meant to use

```
Macaw::dispatch()
```

once, and that is after all routes have been defined, are you sure you are doing that?

Comment: Can you edit your question, pasting in your whole code for the index page

Comment: I just figured it out. Looks like the .htaccess file needs to be outside the actual site folder on XAMPP - then direct all traffic into the site folder.

Comment: Glad your figured it out.